# Override doesn't work

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, overriding

This is my code which I wanted to test

```
@AdminAccessOnly
@Repository
public class TenResImpl extends TenAbstractResImpl implements TenIdRes {

private Invocation request;

protected void messageSend(String iD) {

        Client client = utils.createClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(location).path("/testurl/" + tenantId); 
        Invocation.Builder requestBuilder = webTarget.request();
        Response response = null;
            response = sendRequest();  //here I call the method!!!!!!!

            if (response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() != Status.Family.SUCCESSFUL) {
                // do something
            } else {
                //do something
            }
        } 



protected Response sendRequest() {
    return request.invoke();   // here is the method which should be over written !!!!
 }
}
```

this is my other method in my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestBoot.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = Application.class)
public class TenResImplTest extends TenResImpl{


@Autowired
private TenResImpl tenResImpl;

@Test
public void testMessageSend() throws Exception {    

    this.tenResImpl.messageSend("132");

}



@Override
protected Response sendRequest() {

    StatusType statusType = Mockito.mock(StatusType.class);
    when(statusType.getFamily()).thenReturn(Status.Family.SUCCESSFUL);
    Response response = Mockito.mock(Response.class);
    return response;
 }

}
```

but everytime I debug through it I see that he jumps into the method SendRequest() which is in the class TenResImpl instead of going to my test class.... what I am doing wrong? the access visibility is protected on both and both are in the same package

Comment: Can you show where you call it?

Comment: yes I added some comments above

Comment: Can you show us the instantiation of your class?

Comment: I guess it is up there in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It jumps into the `sendRequest()` method of `TenResImpl` because that's where you called it. Overriding a method doesn't mean that the method which is getting overwritten will never be called again.

To simplify what you've written, let's imagine 2 classes `A` and `B`, where `B` extends `A`. `A` has a `test()` method. If you override `test()` in `B`, calling `test()` on a `B` object will execute the `B` class's `test()`, but calling it on a `A` object will still execute the `A` class's method.

Now let's adapt this to your situation :

Your `TenResImpl` is `A` and your test class is `B`. You're calling `sendRequest()` in `TenResImpl` so, hence what I've explained before, it goes into your `TenResImpl`'s method.

Comment: so there is no way I can test it without calling the sendRequest() from my test class directly?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Hope my answer helped though !